# Chrome: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE when using corsproxy over HTTPS

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, heroku, https

**I have:**

1. Registered my app to work with some social network (register `https://xxx.heroku.com` in social network)
2. Send AJAX request via corsproxy (to bypass Cross Domain restrictions), which do the request to the social netwrok I has registered on:

**Code:**

```
var url = 'cs7-3v4.vk-cdn.net/p17/3f4da74425b00a.mp3?extra=X-fxNwlLKifZltRpJxs4b1XSq0k3NKlSzq3Qse9WG18gWOT_OmO9tCMr9-u3ZhnEmqk4XUxlG55fB18HYpBDcXP3TixE1FKu';
$.get('https://www.corsproxy.com/' + url, function(response) {
    document.body.innerHTML = response;
});
```

**Problem:** Got `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`.

**Question:** *If I changed `https://xxx.heroku.com` to `http://xxx.heroku.com` would it fix an issue?*

Answer (score 0):

> Question: If I changed https://xxx.heroku.com to http://xxx.heroku.com would it fix an issue?

Yes

Answer (score 0):

Ty to run this command : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security.